# FMX Bitmap Image Loading Fail from Socket Stream

Tags: sockets, bitmap, stream, firemonkey

I got some problems with the TImage component of loading bitmap from stream. When i call that my image loading like that.

[Normal Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXftH.png)
[Fullscreen Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLWXe.png)

Okay, but when i build my codes on VCL Application mode its working good.

```
procedure SaveToStream(Stream: TStream; Bitm: TBitmap);
var
  Surface: TBitmapSurface;
begin
  Surface:= TBitmapSurface.Create;
  try
    Surface.Assign(Bitm);
    TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream(Stream, Surface, '.bmp');
  finally
    Surface.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Calling like that,

```
    B := TBitmap.Create;
    BS:= TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      B := ParseData((FData)); // my image data is converting from TByteArray to Bitmap now. Its 
                                  working no problem. 
      SaveToStream(BS, B);
      FrmScreenViewer.ImgScreen.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(BS);
      //FrmScreenViewer.ImgScreen.Bitmap:= B; //I tryed without SaveToStream method but same 
                                                result.
    finally
      B.Free;
      BS.Free;
    end;
```

Are there some limitations on the FMX side? Why isn't working?

ParseData Function (I used RTC Framework and some variables are customizable like RTCByteArray)

```
function ParseData(Data: RtcByteArray): TBitmap;
var
  B: TBitmap;
  M: TRtcByteArrayStream;
begin
  B := TBitmap.Create;
  M := TRtcByteArrayStream.Create(Data);
  try
    B.LoadFromStream(M);
    Result := B;
  finally
    M.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Well, maybe the `ParseData()` function doesn't do its task correctly, after all? We can't know. So what is the result if you use a bitmap from another source?

Comment: @TomBrunberg i added ParseData function.

Comment: I repeat: So what is the result if you use a bitmap from another source

Comment: Source is device? This multi platform app and i tried before several devices and platforms but result is same. I hope I misunderstood you.

Comment: No, I meant that you replace `B := ParseData((FData));` with e.g. `B := TBitmap.CreateFromFile('C:\tmp\00.bmp');` and that you know the file is a correct `.bmp` file. As your `ParseData()` function (that you now have added to your question) appears to be correct, the conclusion must be, that the error is in your `FData`.

Comment: Ahh sorry, okay i fixed, this my mistake some rows overlooked in my function. Thanks @TomBrunberg for answers.